# complex loop in ansible with_together

Tags: ansible

How do I skip empty item in list if I use with_together?

see the code below:

```
- name: get data_files list
  shell: ls -l data_files | awk -F " " {'print $9'}
  register: csv_file_list
- debug: var=csv_file_list

- name: get table name list
  shell: ls -l data_files/ | awk -F " " {'print $9'} | sed -e "s/.csv//g" | sed -e "s/-/./g"
  register: table_list
- debug: var=table_list

- name: copy table from csv to demo db
  shell: psql -U postgres -d demo -c "\copy {{ item.1 }} from /home/ubuntu/data_files/{{ item.0 }} DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER"
  with_together:
    - csv_file_list.stdout_lines
    - table_list.stdout_lines
  when: {{ item.1 }} != ''
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test if `item.1` is not none.

```
when: item.1 != None
```